# Derivation of a discritization of a nonlinear term using FEM

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, mathematical-modeling

I am struggling understanding a discretization of a nonlinear term from the Burgers equation. The term is

$$Z(u) = \int_0^1 \frac{du}{dx}u v dx$$

where $u$ is the solution of the PDE and $v$ is the test function. The assumtion is that
$u = \sum_{j = 1}^n u_j \phi_j(x)$ and $v = \phi_i$ where for the moment we can assume the $\phi$ are the standard hat functions

$$\phi (x)  = 
\begin{cases}
(x - (i - 1)h)/h     & \text{if } x \in [ (i-1)h , ih]\\
(-x + (i +1)h)/h   & \text{if } x \in  [ih, (i + 1)h)]\\
0                 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
In the notes where I got this from assuming the PDE had homogeneous Dirichlet boundary $(u(0) = u(1) = 0)$ , then the following discretization was given

\begin{align}
Z(u) = \frac{1}{6} 
\begin{bmatrix}
u_1 u_2 + u_2^2 \\
-u_1 - u_1 u_2 + u_2 u_3 + u_3^2\\
\vdots \\
-u_{i -1} - u_{i-1} u_{i} + u_i u_{i+1} + u_{i+1}^2\\
\vdots \\
-u_{n -2} - u_{n-2} u_{n-1} + u_{n-1}+ u_{n} + u_{n}^2\\
-u_{n}^2 - u_{n-1} u_{n} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

My issue is that I am not following this at all. What I tried was to look at a generic component and algebra form there

\begin{align}
\left (Z(u) \right)_i &= \int_0^1 \frac{d}{dx}\left( \sum_{j = 1}^n u_j \phi_j(x)\right)\left( \sum_{k = 1}^n u_k \phi_k(x) \right ) \phi_i(x) dx\\
&= \int_0^1 \left( \sum_{j = 1}^n u_j \phi_j'(x)\right)\left( \sum_{k = 1}^n u_k \phi_k(x) \right ) \phi_i(x) dx
\end{align}

braking this into subintervals

\begin{align}
\left (Z(u) \right)_i &= \sum_{i=1}^n \int_{x_{i-1}}^ {x_{i+1}} \left( \sum_{j = 1}^n u_j \phi_j'(x)\right)\left( \sum_{k = 1}^n u_k \phi_k(x) \right ) \phi_i(x) dx
\end{align}

then each local contribution will only depend on $i-1,i,i+1$. I guess what I am trying to then I look at each integral
\begin{align}
\int_{x_{i-1}}^ {x_{i+1}} \left( \sum_{j = 1}^n u_j \phi_j'(x)\right)\left( \sum_{k = 1}^n u_k \phi_k(x) \right ) \phi_i(x) dx = \int_{x_{i-1}}^ {x_{i+1}} \left( u_{i-1} \phi_{i-1}'(x) + u_i \phi_i'(x) +   u_{i+1} \phi_{i+1}'(x) \right)\left( u_{i-1} \phi_{i-1}(x) + u_i \phi_i(x) +   u_{i+1} \phi_{i+1}(x) \right) \phi_i(x)dx
\end{align}

then I guess we have to split the integral again to look at $[x_{i-1},x_i]$ and $[x_i,x_{i+1}]$.

\begin{align}
 \int_{x_{i-1}}^ {x_{i}} \left( u_{i-1} \phi_{i-1}'(x) + u_i \phi_i'(x) +   u_{i+1} \phi_{i+1}'(x) \right)\left( u_{i-1} \phi_{i-1}(x) + u_i \phi_i(x) +   u_{i+1} \phi_{i+1}(x) \right) \phi_i(x)dx
&= \\
\int_{x_{i-1}}^ {x_{i}} \left( 0 + u_i/h  -   u_{i+1}/h \right)\left( u_{i-1} \phi_{i-1}(x) + u_i \phi_i(x) +   u_{i+1} \phi_{i+1}(x) \right) \phi_i(x)dx
\end{align}

where in the above I took the derivative of the basis functions then it think there are standard formulas
$\int_0^1 \phi_i \phi_i = 2/3$ and $\int_0^1 \phi_i \phi_i = 1/6$ , I think that because we are computing this on a shorter domain $[x_{i-1},x_i]$ we will have a multiplication by by an $h$ where that is the length of the domain, but my derivation does not seem like that was given as the correct discritization. I would really appreciate some help here.